# using querybuilder and DQL to pull specific attributes of entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I have the following query:

```
   $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p.id, p.name, p.price, p.cover')
            ->from("SiteMainBundle:Product", 'p')
            ->innerJoin('p.category', 'c')
            ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
            ;
```

And inside my product entity the cover is actually another entity, which looks like this:

```
   /** 
        * @Accessor(getter="getCover") 
    */
    private $cover;
    public function getCover()
    {
        if($this->pictures->count() > 0) {
            return $this->pictures[0];
        }
        return new ProductPicture();
    }
```

However when I do this it gives me an error:

```
"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 32 near 'cover FROM SiteMainBundle:Product': Error: Class Site\\MainBundle\\Entity\\Product has no field or association named cover"
```

I know this is because it is declared as private, but can I call the method getCover from the query builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because of private visibility, but because `cover` is not defined as an entity field.

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Accessor(getter="getCover") 
 */
private $cover;
```

Comment: so how do I get the cover without having to store it as a column in the product

Comment: You can't, your database and entity definitions should be in sync.

Comment: but how is it that when I just do >select('p') it selects the cover as well?

Comment: Maybe the field is not actually called cover then? Maybe you do select on another entity?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load only specific fields, instead of the whole entity, you need to use the [partial object](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html) syntax:

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p.{id,name,price,cover}')
```

This will select only the 4 specific columns you want.